# Module dependency while building scheme project using automake

Tags: scheme, automake, guile

I am trying to build and install a scheme project that has module dependencies using `automake`. However, I keep getting errors as described below.

To demonstrate with a simple example, imagine I have the following project structure:

```
+-a.scm
|
+-libs/
  +-b.scm
  |
  +-c.scm
```

And `module a` depends on `module b` which depends on `module c`. Suppose the files have the following module definition

a.scm

```
(define-module (a)
    #:use-module (a b))
```

b.scm

```
(define-module (a b)
        #:use-module (a c))
```

c.scm

```
(define-module (a c))
```

Here is the `Makefile.am` I am using

```
GOBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.scm=%.go)
moddir=$(prefix)/share/guile/site/$(GUILE_EFFECTIVE_VERSION)
godir=$(libdir)/guile/$(GUILE_EFFECTIVE_VERSION)/site-ccache
ccachedir=$(libdir)/guile/$(GUILE_EFFECTIVE_VERSION)/site-ccache

nobase_mod_DATA = $(SOURCES) $(NOCOMP_SOURCES)
nobase_go_DATA = $(GOBJECTS)


# Make sure source files are installed first, so that the mtime of
# installed compiled files is greater than that of installed source
# files.  See
# <http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/guile-devel/2010-07/msg00125.html>
# for details.
guile_install_go_files = install-nobase_goDATA
$(guile_install_go_files): install-nobase_modDATA

CLEANFILES = $(GOBJECTS)
GUILE_WARNINGS = -Wunbound-variable -Warity-mismatch -Wformat
SUFFIXES = .scm .go
.scm.go:
    $(AM_V_GEN)$(top_builddir)/env $(GUILE_TOOLS) compile $(GUILE_WARNINGS) -o "$@" "$<"

SOURCES = \
            c.scm \
            b.scm \
            a.scm 

EXTRA_DIST = \
    boostrap \
    env.in
```

Building the project with `make` gives me the error below:

> no module for (a c)

How can I fix the above error and build the project successfully with all interdependencies between the modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guile has a simple module search pattern - it looks in every directory defined in `GUILE_LOAD_PATH` for:

- file `a` and `a.scm` - when `#:use-module (a)`
- file `bb/a` and `bb/a.scm` - when `#:use-module (bb a)`
- file `ccc/bb/a` and `ccc/bb/a.scm` - when `#:use-module (ccc bb a)`

  etc...

If you keep your projects in `/home/user/proj/` directory, you should `export GUILE_LOAD_PATH="/home/user/proj"`.

From now on, you can easily load and switch to modules using `,m (<module-name>)`. So if project you are working on is located in `/home/user/proj/proj-a/` directory, you can start guile and type `,m (proj-a a)` to automatically load your `a.scm` file, just change module definition to `(proj-a a)`.

Next - in your case `b.scm` and `c.scm` files are in `libs/` subdirectory, so you should `#:use-module (proj-a lib b)` and ...`(proj-a lib c)`, and also change module names in `b.scm` and `c.scm` accordingly.

Guile manual related to modules is very nice https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Modules.html#Modules (it's enough to read first 4 chapters).

Comment: So `(define-module (a))` doesn't have any effect?

Comment: @xabush_semrie I updated my answer, please let me know if something is not clear

Comment: Thanks. One additional question I have is. Let's say b.scm imports the `(srfi srfi-1)` and a.scm, as already established, imports module b. Let's say module a also uses function in `(srfi srfi-1)`. Does module a have to re-import `(srfi srfi-1)`  or will it be imported along with module b?

Comment: When you define module, You define dependencies and exports for this module only. Module `b` should export **all** (srfi srfi-1) functions to make them accessible in `a`. And that's not practical, so you should import (srfi srfi-1) module in both, `a` and `b`.